# Using multithreading in c++11 to fully utilize CPU with OpenCV

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, c++11

I am writing a console C++ program that analyzes films for color (and other properties) using the OpenCV Library. I have reached a significant bottleneck with the `cap.retrieve()` function (similar to `cap.read()`). This operation takes the longest out of any single function I call in my program, and takes significantly longer when reading HD videos. Despite this, I am still getting less than 50% CPU utilization when I run my program.

I have since decided that the best course of action would be to try to reach full utilization by creating a new thread each time I want to read (or "retrieve) an image from the video, with a specific maximum number of threads based upon the CPU specs. I have done some reading on the basics of multithreading with C++11, but am unsure where to start.

Here is the section of my code I would like to multithread:

```
// Run until all frames have been read
while(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) != cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) {

  // look at but do not read the frame
  cap.grab();

  // only process if user wants to process it
  // eg: if resolution = 20 then will only process every 20 frames
  if (int(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)) % resolution == 0) {

    // multithread everything inside this loop??

    Mat frame;

    // retrieve frame and get data to solve for avg time to retrieve
    double t1 = (double)getTickCount();
    bool bSuccess = cap.retrieve(frame);
    t1 = ((double)getTickCount() - t1)/getTickFrequency();
    readT.push_back(t1);

    //if not success, break loop
    if (!bSuccess) {
      break;
    }

    // Get avg color and data to calculate total avg color
    // get data to solve for avg time to calc mean
    HIDDEN

   // adds a single row of the avg color to the colorCloud mat
   HIDDEN
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Anything from links to resources to tutorials or pseudocode would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: start by choosing a multithreading library to use, like boost or pthread.

Comment: because I have heard only complaints on c11 threads.